# Ninject get method set constructor argument to null

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

I am using Ninject for implementing IoC/DI in my application. It has been working well in the whole application except one case, where i am setting a constructor argument of type User Defined Class.

This class has four properties, all of them are of type user defined type, All of them are serialized enums.

Now when i resolve the dependency of kernel, it throws me the exception as constructor arguments values set to null. I don't know why is it.

Is it because of seriazlizeable enums or something else. There is no way i could change my types, so please suggest me something in the context where i don't need to change the types.

**Edit**

```
IManager manager = GlobalData.Kernel.Get<IManager> (new ConstructorArgument("context", Context)); 
// Context Class code is here 
public class Context { 
    public string ContextCode { get; set; } 
    public Module Module { get; set; } 
    public Screen Screen { get; set; } }
```

Module and Screen are Serializable Enums

Comment: IManager manager = GlobalData.Kernel.Get<IManager>
                (new ConstructorArgument("context", Context));    Context Class code is here   public class Context
    {
        public string ContextCode { get; set; }
        public Module Module { get; set; }
        public Screen Screen { get; set; }
         } Module and Screen are Serializable Enums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your Context passed to Get as constructor argument is Null.

Comment: No, i checked it before passing it to Get method, its not null, the issue was the variable name i passed to ConstructorArgument was not similar to one specified in class

public class a
{
publi a(Context consArg)
}

and i use

ConstructorArgument("ConsArg",context);

problem is constructor argument is case senstive

Thanks for your inputs

Remo, it'll be very helpful if you suggest me something so this static string dependency was resolved.

Comment: All I can say is specify a binding for the Context. For more there is far to little information in your post.

Comment: I just want to replace static string to some variable value, so if later on someone change the constructor variable identifier, it won't break my code.